# Why does some page components not getting fully loaded in Page_Init of ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, components, pageload

In page-init, view state and some other components don't get loaded. Which are they?

Why do they loaded in Page-Load only? What does the need of Page-Init then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Page_Init**:
 Fired when page is initialised. This includes postbacks. All server controls are created to their initial, unaltered state. First step in page lifecycle, controls are organized hierarchically.

**Page_Load**:
 Controls fully loaded, if the page is a postback, then the controls are loaded with their viewstate.

In other words, *Viewstate* only comes into effect on Page_Load, where (if Viewstate is enabled for the control/page), the controls previous state is reloaded.

Hope that helps.